# Fruit ninja type game in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a ninja fruit style game in javascript but problems are happening. I have this if statements that compare the variable "fruit" with the index of the "fruits" array. The problem is when I "eliminate" a fruit the other if statements doenst work.

That's how the game needs to work:

1 You start the game, a random name of a fruit appears for you to click on.

2 You click in the image of the fruit and it disappears, in this click another random fruit is generated.

3 An then you finish the game, that's prety much this.

So it's kind hard to explain, but its the same logic as the ninja fruit game. And I dont know if I need to use the shift function to eliminate the fruits in the array as well.

```js
var fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'];
var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length)];
document.getElementById("frut").innerHTML = fruit;
if (fruit == fruits[0]) {
  bana.onclick = function() {
    var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length)];

    document.getElementById("frut").innerHTML = fruit;

    bana.style.display = "none";
  }
}
if (fruit == fruits[1]) {
  app.onclick = function() {
    var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length)];
    document.getElementById("frut").innerHTML = fruit;
    app.style.display = "none";
  }
}
if (fruit == fruits[2]) {

  pin.onclick = function() {
    var fruit = fruits[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length)];
    document.getElementById("frut").innerHTML = fruit;
    pin.style.display = "none";
  }
}
function movFruit() {

  document.getElementById("info").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("fruitAnimation").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("insructions").style.display = "none";

  var elem = document.getElementById("fruitAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#fruitAnimation {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fr {
  float: left;
  padding: 80px;
}

#info {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#insructions {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>JSfruit</title>
</head>





<body>
  <div id="info">
    <h1>Fruit: <span id="frut"></span></h1>
  </div>


  <button onclick="movFruit() " style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;"><h4>Start the game</h4></button>




  <div id="fruitAnimation">
    <div class="fr" id="bana">
      <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/5c87/f/2016/322/8/9/banana_pixel_art_by_fireprouf-daosk9z.png" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
    <div class="fr" id="app">
      <img src="https://art.ngfiles.com/images/404000/404664_thexxxreaper_pixel-apple.png?f1454891997" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
    <div class="fr" id="pin">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c2/f9/e9/c2f9e9f8d332da97a836513de98f7b29.jpg" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
  </div>

  <span id="insructions">Click in the fruits and erase them!</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're only attaching handlers to the fruit images at the top level, in your `if` statements - but once those statements run and the main block finishes, it doesn't get run again.

You should attach handlers to *all* fruit images at once in the beginning, and then in the handlers, check to see the clicked fruit was valid.

If you're assigning text to an element, assign to `textContent`, not `innerHTML`; `textContent` is quicker, safer, and more predictable.

```js
const fruits = ['Banana', 'Apple', 'Pineapple'];
const getRandomFruit = () => {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruits.length);
  const fruit = fruits[randomIndex];
  document.getElementById("frut").textContent = fruit;
  fruits.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  return fruit;
};
let fruitToClickOn = getRandomFruit();


bana.onclick = function() {
  if (fruitToClickOn !== 'Banana') return;
  bana.style.display = "none";
  fruitToClickOn = getRandomFruit();
}
app.onclick = function() {
  if (fruitToClickOn !== 'Apple') return;
  app.style.display = "none";
  fruitToClickOn = getRandomFruit();
}
pin.onclick = function() {
  if (fruitToClickOn !== 'Pineapple') return;
  pin.style.display = "none";
  fruitToClickOn = getRandomFruit();
}


function movFruit() {

  document.getElementById("info").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("fruitAnimation").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("insructions").style.display = "none";

  var elem = document.getElementById("fruitAnimation");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 350) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#fruitAnimation {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.fr {
  float: left;
  padding: 80px;
}

#info {
  display: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#insructions {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>JSfruit</title>
</head>





<body>
  <div id="info">
    <h1>Fruit: <span id="frut"></span></h1>
  </div>


  <button onclick="movFruit() " style="display: table; margin: 0 auto;"><h4>Start the game</h4></button>




  <div id="fruitAnimation">
    <div class="fr" id="bana">
      <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/5c87/f/2016/322/8/9/banana_pixel_art_by_fireprouf-daosk9z.png" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
    <div class="fr" id="app">
      <img src="https://art.ngfiles.com/images/404000/404664_thexxxreaper_pixel-apple.png?f1454891997" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
    <div class="fr" id="pin">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c2/f9/e9/c2f9e9f8d332da97a836513de98f7b29.jpg" width="60" height="60">
    </div>
  </div>

  <span id="insructions">Click in the fruits and erase them!</span>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: **Start the game** button works only once. Does not work for after that.

Comment: Thanks! Thats the resut i wanted. I just don't understand this part **if (fruitToClickOn !== 'Banana') return;** why not just equal? and why return? i remove both the return and the exclamation point and got the same result. I think i'm to dumb to understand this logic LOL.

Comment: @VicJordan yeah a lot to improve,  this is just a study case or prototype whatever you wanna call, i'm doing this just to train my skills in javascript.

Comment: @jarwin Returning early like that cuts down on indentation (more indentation = more cognitive load). Of course, you could do `if (fruitToClickOn === 'Banana') { // block here ` if you want - same effect, just harder to read.